# Make deleted posts visible for users <10k when they flagged it

Tags: feature-request, flags, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently I flagged an answer as "Not an answer", but the flag was declined giving the following reason:

> This is not just not an answer; it is spam. Please review more
>   carefully.

Well, usually I *do* review carefully, so I think I have missed something with this one. Now I'm a firm believer that you should learn from your mistakes and therefore I'd like to see why I screwed up. But since I have far too few reputation points to see deleted posts, I can't.

I'm absolutely OK with the rule that you need 10k to see every deleted post. Nonetheless I think that it would be useful to allow users that flagged a post to still see it after deletion even if they don't have 10k.

So here's my proposal: make deleted posts visible for users <10k when they flagged it.

Comment: Ideally, I'd even say it should just be visible on the flag review page itself. If the intent is really to educate about the flag reasoning

Comment: If you need to know what was in a post, you could just ask about that on meta.

Comment: In this case, the post contained: *It is easy to do so \[by\]\[1\] following guidelines.* linking `by` to a spam site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure, I could ask for a single post on meta. But I think that mods already have enough work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks anyway for showing me. I must have mistaken it as a link only answer then.

Comment: If you reviewed it, [you can, in fact, see it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed). So this must have been an answer that you came across organically, instead of finding it in the review queues?

Comment: We could try to guess why you could flag a post you cannot see.  But that wasn't the point of the moderator assistance you got, next time be sure to consider that a post might be malicious.  Hard to imagine on a site that helps so many people, but it does attract riff-raff.

Comment: @Cody: they did review it; see https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22464747

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for pointing out the cross site dupe. I have always used my flag summary page and haven't noticed the history tab on the queue. Since what I proposed is already possible, should I delete this question?

Comment: Cross-site duplicates aren't really a thing. :-) If you're satisfied with the current implementation, feel free to post an answer explaining how it works and linking to the question on MSE. Otherwise, since you haven't gotten any answers, you can edit your question to clarify the feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some limitations this can already be done. As explained in the [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228955/392713) that @CodyGray linked in his comment, if you raised the flag in one of the review queues you can click on the `History` tab of the queue:

[image]

There you can click on the link at the right of the question title. This brings you back to the review page where you can see the post even if it is deleted.

The limitation is that this is only possible for the review queues. If you flagged a post while visiting it from, for example, the main page you're out of luck.